# regular expression for asp.net validation control

Tags: asp.net, regex

In an ASP.NET Listview, I need to raise an error with a RegularExpressionValidator control if a string in an textbox control exceeds a given length.  I have minimal experience with regular expressions and hopefully someone can tell me if this is a good use of regular expressions and help me get started with the expression.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, use a Regular Expression Validator and set the expression to something like this:

```
^([\S\s]{0,10})$
```

Replace the 4 with your desired max lenght.

Update:

```
<asp:TextBox id="wtxtTPP" Runat="server" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ValidationExpression="^([\S\s]{0,0})$" 
        ControlToValidate="wtxtTPP" />
```

Or

Use `MaxLength` Property

like

```
 <asp:TextBox id="wtxtTPP" Runat="server" MaxLength="10"/>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if someone disables or modifies MaxLength using Firebug (for example), they can submit the form with more than 4 characters in your textbox.  You will need the RegularExpressionValidator (or a server-side validation approach) to ensure the value is not greater than 4 characters.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, your RegExp example works perfectly and has the advantage of giving a normal validation error message.  Both the these methods together works very well - along with the server side.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need validator to do that. Just set `TextBox.MaxLength` property to your desired length.

> [`TextBox.MaxLength` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>
> Gets or sets the maximum number of characters allowed in the text box.

Comment: Thank you very much - exactly what I needed even if I feel pretty dumb for missing such a simple solution.  Live and Learn!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the properties of regular expression:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
AccessKey="string"
AssociatedControlID="string"
BackColor="color name|#dddddd"
BorderColor="color name|#dddddd"
BorderStyle="NotSet|None|Dotted|Dashed|Solid|Double|Groove|Ridge|
    Inset|Outset"
BorderWidth="size"
ControlToValidate="string"
CssClass="string"
Display="None|Static|Dynamic"
EnableClientScript="True|False"
Enabled="True|False"
EnableTheming="True|False"
EnableViewState="True|False"
ErrorMessage="string"
Font-Bold="True|False"
Font-Italic="True|False"
Font-Names="string"
Font-Overline="True|False"
Font-Size="string|Smaller|Larger|XX-Small|X-Small|Small|Medium|
            Large|X-Large|XX-Large"
    Font-Strikeout="True|False"
Font-Underline="True|False"
ForeColor="color name|#dddddd"
Height="size"
ID="string"
OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
OnInit="Init event handler"
OnLoad="Load event handler"
OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
OnUnload="Unload event handler"
runat="server"
SetFocusOnError="True|False"
SkinID="string"
Style="string"
TabIndex="integer"
Text="string"
ToolTip="string"
ValidationExpression="string"
ValidationGroup="string"
Visible="True|False"
Width="size"
/>
```

You can refer to [MSDN docs for RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more detail.